# Free Will vs Destiny

Tags: free-will, determinism, reality

**Is living, believing having free will the destiny(predetermined truth)of our life?
Do we really have free will or we just believe to have free will?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do defenders of libertarian freewill reconcile it with constraints imposed by the laws of physics?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/30415/how-do-defenders-of-libertarian-freewill-reconcile-it-with-constraints-imposed-b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free will is our ability to decide what we do.

You really do have that ability. You act in a controlled fashion, your actions are not random and pointless. There is no reason to even suspect that there might be someone else controlling your actions. All evidence points at you.