# What is character, and what role does it play in the decision making of an agent, according to proponents of libertarian free will?

Tags: ontology, physics, causality, moral-agency, libertarianism-free-will

I understand libertarian free will as an agent's ability to choose otherwise, or having more than one course of action available to them, when making a choice at time *t*, given a fixed past up to *t*. However, after having partaken in multiple discussions related to the concept of free will on the Christianity site (for the curious, see [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/95960/61679), [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/95956/61679), [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/95981/61679), [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/95830/61679)), I've noticed that the concept of *character* is very important for at least some proponents of libertarian freedom. To illustrate this, let me quote this [answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/95831/61679):

> The "missing link" here is ***character.***  God has free will, and is fully capable of being tempted and enticed to do evil, but consistently chooses to use that free will in benevolent and righteous ways.

Or this [answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/95957/61679):

> Christians have free-will, but their purpose in life is to **develop perfect characters that *always freely choose* not to sin**.
> They can *develop* this God-like character, but by definition no one can be *created* with it.

Yet, I still have to understand what *character* is in the first place. Is there a rigorous definition of *character*? Does *character* exist as a "thing" in the first place (i.e., what is the ontological status of *character*)? Does *character* have any measurable or detectable causal effects on reality? For example, does an agent's *character* influence said agent in a way that determines or narrows the range of options available to them at time *t*, and if so, how?

And what is the relationship between an agent's *character* and the laws of physics? Is *character* nothing but an emergent property of the laws of physics, in the sense that the concept of *character* is a convenient high-level abstraction, but ultimately adds nothing new to what the laws of physics can already explain? Is a person's *character* nothing but the current state of the neural wiring of their brain? Is *character* nothing but brain chemistry? Or is *character* something beyond the laws of physics, not reducible to them, and different from free will at the same time?

And if *character* goes beyond the laws of physics, where is the information of this *character* stored? Can it change/be updated over time? Does it obey its own "character update rules"?

In short, what is *character*, and what role does it play in the decision making of an agent, according to proponents of libertarian free will?

---

<sub>Regarding my sub-question about the relationship between *character* and the laws of physics, this question is closely related: [How do defenders of libertarian freewill reconcile it with constraints imposed by the laws of physics?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/30415/66156)</sub>

Comment: "*Sow a thought and reap an act; sow an act and reap a habit; sow a habit and reap a character; sow a character and reap a destiny.*"

Comment: "I [God] have set before you life and death, blessing and curse: therefore choose life" (Deuteronomy 30:19). Isaiah 7:14-16 - *The virgin shall be with child and bear a son. He shall be called Emmanuel (A name which means 'God is with us'). He shall be eating curds and honey by the time he learns to reject the bad and choose the good.* Developing the character to reject the bad and choose the good via free will and learning lessons over a long life means avoidance of sin and obedience to Jewish law. Christians incorporate free will, sin, and character. Sinners can obtain grace through Jesus.

Comment: @ScottRowe: Beat me to it!

Comment: Scott Rowe and @CriglCragl. That quote says nothing about libertarian free will or the laws of physics or the interplay between the three, so I'm still left clueless :(

Comment: There is no interplay between the three, they are all just stuff humans made up. It is thinking *about* something, not thinking *it*. The 'it' part doesn't exist. We are fantasizing.

Comment: @ScottRowe Interesting view. Would you like to expand on that in an answer?

Comment: A way of looking at is: how will the answer to this question help you?

Comment: @ScottRowe I cannot answer that without knowing the answer first. Post an answer and then I will be able to answer your question.

Comment: A way of finding out is: what prompted you to ask this particular question? Usually answers are a matter for the asker to determine. Or the old saying: "*All the answers are within.*" Which seems like a religious or spiritual way of looking at it. But if I know what prompted the question, I could direct my answer that way. Because I could answer the same question from different people differently.

Comment: @ScottRowe I'm just trying to understand how libertarian free will works. See my most recently asked question: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/100333/66156

Answer (score 3):

["Empirical Approaches to Moral Character"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/moral-character-empirical/) is a good overview of what you are asking about (c.f. the [more general such article](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/moral-character/)), though see also §4 of [a different SEP entry](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/moral-psych-emp/#VirtEthiSkepAbouChar) for empiricist skepticism about character as such. The SEP article on virtue ethics [starts with the remark that](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ethics-virtue/#Virt):

> A virtue is an excellent trait of character. It is a disposition, well entrenched in its possessor—something that, as we say, goes all the way down, unlike a habit such as being a tea-drinker—to notice, expect, value, feel, desire, choose, act, and react in certain characteristic ways. To possess a virtue is to be a certain sort of person with a certain complex mindset. A significant aspect of this mindset is the wholehearted acceptance of a distinctive range of considerations as reasons for action.

Some religious analysts frame such issues in cognitive (or ["noetic"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/sin-christian/#NoetEffeSin)) terms, so we find an intersection with [virtue epistemology](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/epistemology-virtue/):

> Virtue responsibilists (e.g., Battaly, Code, Hookway, Montmarquet, and Zagzebski) understand intellectual virtues to include cultivated character traits such as conscientiousness and open-mindedness; call these ‘trait-virtues’. Their approach is broadly aligned with internalist sympathies in epistemology and deeply concerned with cognition’s ethical dimensions and implications.

*Akrasia* ([weakness of will](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/weakness-will/)) connects up with any or all of the above topics:

> The phrase “all things considered” is not, as it might seem, merely a minor difference in wording that allows weakness of will to get off on a technicality. Rather, that phrase marks an important contrast in logical form to which we would need to attend in any case in order properly to understand the structure of practical reasoning. For that phrase indicates a judgment that is *conditional* or *relational* rather than *all-out* or *unconditional* in form; and that difference is crucial.

I.e., one might think of moral development as improving one's cognitive standing, of moving (by the gathering of moral "evidence" or the specification of moral reasoning) from all-things-considered to all-out judgments; and this improvement might be construed as character-theoretic (our virtuous traits are built up as strongly as possible when we pass the relevant all-out thresholds).

Is this all something that happens in a "physical" way? [Immanuel Kant claimed that the active part of the mind plays into moral cognition](https://tannerlectures.utah.edu/_resources/documents/a-to-z/o/oneill97.pdf) and reverses the order of empirical cognition: rather than proceed from apprehension to understanding to reason, we proceed from reason to understanding to apprehension (that last stage here is ["respect"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/respect/#KantAccoRespForPers) as a *feeling* "wrought by reason"). Such an account is not meant to be absolutely counterphysical, albeit it is not said to be comprehensible on finite scientific grounds, either. If a resolution to the question of character as formed by libertarian willpower were to be embedded in a physicalist theory, this resolution would mean that a physicalist description of libertarian willpower itself had been compellingly realized (something we have yet to achieve as an academic community).

Answer (score -1):

Character is simply the agent's personality, his preferences and values. The agent chooses to do things that serve his preferences, values, needs and long term plans.

These are psychological properties that have nothing to do with physics. There is no conflict between free will and physics.

Morality is how the agent's character aligns with the values of his community.

Comment: Again, references or at least an argument accompanying the assertions would be welcome.

Comment: @armand What assertions? I am not pushing any theories or opinions. This is all common knowledge, nothing controversial. Do you need a dictionary reference for every word?

Comment: How many years since we had this conversation for the first time? For example, many would disagree that "There is no conflict between free will and physics" (I, for one, particularly since we are talking about libertarian free will). This is not something you took from a dictionary. It's pure opinion, which is discouraged as answers on the site. Where does it come from? What thinkers are you referencing? Why do you think that way? You are of course entitled to your attitude, but dont whine when you get downvoted without comments after *years* of refusing to respect the philosophy SE policy.

Comment: @armand It is *not* an opinion, a judgement of right or wrong, good or bad. It is only stating two obvious, observable and verified facts: we do decide what we do and no laws of physics are broken. If you wish to disagree, it is your responsibility to prove either of these facts false. Are some laws of physics broken?  Does someone else control our actions?

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/opinion since you like dictionaries so much and consider their definitions are universally valid

Comment: @armand My statement is still not an opinion, by any meaning of the word. You cannot turn facts into opinions simply by saying you disagree. Neither of these facts is a theory trying to explain something. They are just observations of what is happening in reality. I think you have an emotional attitude to the concept of free will. You want to define it as something else than the ability to make decisions. If that is the case, I can rephrase my statement: "The ability to make decisions is not in conflict with physics."

Comment: @Mark case in point.

Comment: *"The agent chooses to do things that serve his preferences, values, needs and long term plans."* - How is this done in a libertarian way? This statement is perfectly consistent with causal determinism. Can you clarify? *"These are psychological properties that have nothing to do with physics. There is no conflict between free will and physics."* - How is it possible for psychology not to be based on physics? Are you defending mind-body dualism here? Are you implicitly rejecting metaphysical naturalism? Are you assuming the existence of a soul/spirit world/the supernatural? Please clarify.

Comment: @Mark In causal determinism there are no agents, choices, preferences, values, needs or plans. There are only causes and effects, nothing else. Psychology and physics are completely different branches of science studying different things. I am not defending or rejecting anything. The mind and the body do different things anyway, the mind processes information and the body processes matter and energy. Nothing supernatural, just normal business as usual. The mind thinks and the body does.

Comment: @PerttiRuismäki *" In causal determinism there are no agents, choices, preferences, values, needs or plans. There are only causes and effects, nothing else."* - Citation needed? Can you please edit your answer and clarify all this? *"Psychology and physics are completely different branches of science studying different things."* - But everything boils down to physics, since the mind emerges from the brain, and the brain follows the laws of physics, unless you believe in some sort of mind-body dualism and the existence of something beyond physics, which is fine, but please make it explicit.

Comment: @Mark Please, look up the definition of causal determinism.

Comment: @Mark Everything does *not* boil down to or emerge from physics. Mind is just a living brain's capacity to process information. Information itself is immaterial stuff with no measurable physical properties. Laws of physics don't apply in the processing of information. This is not a belief, this is basic science. Information does not exist "beyond" physics. "Besides" or "outside of" physics would be better.

Comment: @PerttiRuismäki Please edit your answer and cite sources.

Comment: @Mark I have no idea about how should I improve my answer. There are no sources for common knowledge. Everyone knows the distinction between psychology and physics.

Comment: @PerttiRuismäki `Laws of physics don't apply in the processing of information. This is not a belief, this is basic science.` So the computer I'm using right now to type this, which is clearly an information processing device, is not physical, and cannot be explained with physics, correct? Again. Citation needed. `Everyone knows the distinction between psychology and physics.` They certainly are different disciplines, but that doesn't meant that one cannot be reduced to the other. This is actually a hotly debated topic.

Comment: See e.g. https://neurosciencenews.com/decision-making-quantum-physics-psychology-2639/, https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1569494/, https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-connection-between-physics-and-psychology

Comment: @Mark The computer is only a tool to help you with information processing. It doesn't know or understand anything. It doesn't deal with ideas, it deals with voltages and input device movements. Psychology deals with ideas, physics deals with matter and energy. There is no way they could be reduced to one or the other. But there are attempts to build bridges between them, here's an example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iBCctObTHGg